# Extracting selective text using beautiful soup and write the result in CSV

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract selective text from website [https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&groups=business&sort=extras_harvest_portal%20asc%2C%20score%20desc%2C%20metadata_modified%20desc&_organization_limit=0&organization=reservebankofaustralia&_groups_limit=0]

and have written code using beautiful soup:
`

```
wiki = "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&groups=business&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&organization=reservebankofaustralia&_groups_limit=0"
page= urllib.request.urlopen(wiki)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
data2 = soup.find_all('h3', class_="dataset-heading")

data3 = []
getdata = []
for link in data2:
    data3  = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile('/dataset/', re.IGNORECASE))
for data in data3:
      getdata = data.text
      print(getdata)

len(getdata)
`
```

My HTML is like :

```html
<a href = "/dataset/banks-assets, class = "label" data-format = "xls">XLS<\a>
```

When I am running above code I am getting text that I want but 'XLS' word is coming alternatively, I want to remove 'XLS' and want to parse remaining text in csv in one column.My output is :

- Banks – Assets
- XLS
- Consolidated Exposures – Immediate and Ultimate
        Risk Basis
- XLS
- Foreign Exchange Transactions and Holdings of
        Official Reserve Assets
- XLS
- Finance Companies and General Financiers
        – Selected Assets and Liabilities
- XLS
- Liabilities and Assets –
        Monthly XLS Consolidated Exposures – Immediate Risk Basis –
        International Claims by Country
- XLS
  and so on.......

I checked whether above output is list. It was given list but it has only one element but as I have shown above my output is many texts.
  Please help me out with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the purpose is only to remove XLS rows from result column, then it can be reached, for example, ths way:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
wiki = "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&groups=business&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&organization=reservebankofaustralia&_groups_limit=0"
page= urlopen(wiki)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
data2 = soup.find_all('h3', class_="dataset-heading")

    data3 = []
    getdata = []
    for link in data2:
        data3  = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile('/dataset/', re.IGNORECASE))
    for data in data3:
        if data.text.upper() != 'XLS':
            getdata.append(data.text)
    print(getdata)
```

You will get a list with text you need. Then it can be easily transformed, for example, to `DataFrame`, where this data will appear as a column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1'], data=getdata)
```

output:

```
                                                 col1
0                                      Banks – Assets
1   Consolidated Exposures – Immediate and Ultimat...
2   Foreign Exchange Transactions and Holdings of ...
3   Finance Companies and General Financiers – Sel...
4                    Liabilities and Assets – Monthly
5   Consolidated Exposures – Immediate Risk Basis ...
6        Consolidated Exposures – Ultimate Risk Basis
7   Banks – Consolidated Group off-balance Sheet B...
8        Liabilities of Australian-located Operations
9   Building Societies – Selected Assets and Liabi...
10  Consolidated Exposures – Immediate Risk Basis ...
11         Banks – Consolidated Group Impaired Assets
12  Assets and Liabilities of Australian-Located O...
13                                      Managed Funds
14            Daily Net Foreign Exchange Transactions
15        Consolidated Exposures-Immediate Risk Basis
16                                  Public Unit Trust
17                            Securitisation Vehicles
18            Assets of Australian-located Operations
19                 Banks – Consolidated Group Capital
```

Putting to csv:

```
df.to_csv('C:\Users\Username\output.csv')
```

Comment: @Arti, any feedback? comments? was it helpful to you?

Comment: @ Dmitriy,it was helpful as i learned new things but I beforehand converted things into dict , you can see my answer post above. but there also I am stuck in putting things into csv. Please check and help in getting out of it.- Arti123

Comment: @Arti, easiest way to put data to csv is using method that I added to the bottom rows of my solution=)
I'll check your code later when I have time.
Aslo if my answer suits you can you please accept it by putting green check mark?

Comment: someone deleted my post, let me undelete it